# Android Home Screen like effect flickering problem when set child.setvisibility(View.Visible)

Tags: android, flicker, visible, viewflipper, homescreen

I have made a sample application to flip through different layouts in a viewflipper.

XML is basically (pseudo-code)

```
<ViewFlipper>
<LinearLayout><TextView text:"this is the first page" /></LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout><TextView text:"this is the second page" /></LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout><TextView text:"this is the third page" /></LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

And in Java code,

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN {
   oldTouchValue = event.getX()
} case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP {
   //depending on Direction, do viewFlipper.showPrevious or viewFlipper.showNext
   //after setting appropriate animations with appropriate start/end locations
} case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE {
   //Depending on the direction
   nextScreen.setVisibility(View.Visible)
   nextScreen.layout(l, t, r, b) // l computed appropriately
   CurrentScreen.layout(l2, t2, r2, b2) // l2 computed appropriately
}
```

Above pseudo code works well moving linearlayouts inside viewflipper when dragging on the screen (just like the home screen).

The problem is when I do nextScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE). When the next screen is set visible, it flickers on the screen before moving to its appropriate position. (I guess it is made visible at 0 location.)

Is there a way to load the next screen without making it flicker on the screen? I want it to be loaded (made visible) out of screen so it doesn't flicker.

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Answer (score 3):

+1. I'm having the exact same problem. I tried switching the layout() and setVisible() calls to no effect.

Update:
The problem turns out to be the correct sequence in setting the visibility of the nextScreen view. If you set the visibility to VISIBLE *before* calling layout(), you get the flicker at position 0 as you noticed. But if you call layout() first, it gets ignored because the visibility is GONE. I did two things to fix this:

1. Set the visibility to INVISIBLE before first layout() call. This differs from GONE in that the layout() is executed - you just don't see it.
2. Set the visibility to VISIBLE asynchronously, so the layout() and related messages are processed first

In code:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    nextScreen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //from View.GONE

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    nextScreen.layout(l, t, r, b);
    if (nextScreen.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
    //the view is not visible, so send a message to make it so
    mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(mHandler, 0));
}

private class ViewHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        nextScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

More elegant/easier solutions are welcome!