# Android viewflipper flicker

Tags: android, flicker, viewflipper, swipe

I have a ViewFlipper with multiple views added dynamically. I override onTouchEvent (and onInterceptTouchEvent) in order to get the down, move and up events on the views, so I know when to animate left and right.

Now everything works fine, except that there is a small flicker (one of the other views is displayed on top for a split second) at the beginning of the swipe. This only happens after the first swipe is done.

I looked at the source code for the Home screen app on Android, which helped a lot, but they don't use the ViewFlipper, so it's a little different.

Did anyone encounter the same problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I encountered the same problem. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3544826/430680 "my answer") to a similar question.