# Android view Visibility change causes screen to flicker

Tags: android

I currently have a layout where, on the end of a video being played, changes the visibility of a fullscreen imageview to VISIBLE. Whenever this happens, the screen slightly flickers. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
public class VideoTestFlip extends SherlockActivity implements OnCompletionListener
{
ImageView surprise;
VideoView video;
ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video_splash);
    video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewflipper);
    Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_down);
    Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_up);

    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(in);
    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(out);
    surprise = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.surprise);
    video.setVideoPath("android.resource://com.mezzolab.danariely/raw/" + R.raw.splash_low_5);

 video.start();
    video.setOnCompletionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
{

    surprise.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    viewFlipper.showNext();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see your code, but a lot of the time this is because your sequence of events is off. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544826/android-home-screen-like-effect-flickering-problem-when-set-child-setvisibility)

EDIT:
Now that your code is up: What you did doesn't seem like it should have any flickering behavior. The only thing I can think to do is to try and set it visible asynchronously. Make a handler:

```
private class ViewHandler extends Handler {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    surprise.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
}
```

then call it to make the `ImageView` `View.VISIBLE` by calling the handler:

```
mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(mHandler, 0));
```

Comment: Is that `ImageView` `View.GONE` or `View.Invisible`?

Comment: it is set as View.Invisible

Comment: you were right, it was smthing with the order of events, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use animation to avoid this flickering.