# Toolbar flickers when TableLayout setvisibility gone

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a problem in android application. When I click on the screen to hide the toolbar it flickers. while disappearing it displays the content and then disappear.

I have already applied this solution: [Stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090356/android-view-visibility-change-causes-screen-to-flicker)

**Code:**

```
content_main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (toolbar.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
```

**Xml:**

```
    <TableLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:rowCount="5"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="culha.roomdispaly.MainActivity"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
   <TableRow
----------
      </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```